# Cannot access/see "Events" for Agents

Tags: lotus-notes, domino-designer-eclipse

In Lotus Notes Designer 8.5 when I open a LotusScript Agent I cannot specify the trigger Event. The Event tab only shows "No event specified for this element". I have seen event parameters before but now they are all gone.

If I create a Formular Agent I can access Agent Properties and the trigger event but not with LotusScript Agent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See **Properties** tab, it's there. If Properties tab is not visible goto Windows -> Show Eclipse Views -> Properties.

Note that this is not the traditional Notes properties box which is shown for @Formula agents.